# How to use gulp-connect with IIS

Tags: iis, gulp

I'm using the library gulp-connect to refresh my browser when I change something in my frontend... but like you know it works in a server like localhost:8080... the problems is that my backend is in IIS.I wonder if is there some way to connect my IIS with gulp-connet to refresh my code when I change it in localhost:80 (IIS) ? Maybe a middleware or something like that?

Comment: Did you find a way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

You would be better off using browsersync:

```
//Set up the proxy
const browserSyncStart = () => { browserSync.init({ proxy: 'localhost' }); };

//set up a watch
const watcher = () => { return gulp.watch(src).on('all', () => { compileLess().on('end', publish); }); };

//Let the publish function also reload the browser
export const publish = () => {
  // Check if the folder exists
  if (fs.existsSync(config.publishPath)) {
    //copy from /dist to /wwwroot
    del(config.publishPath + 'dist/**/*', { force: true });
    gulp.src(config.theming.dist + '/**/*').pipe(gulp.dest(config.publishPath + 'dist'));
    browserSync.reload();
  } else {
    log(c.red(config.publishPath + ' does not exist.'));
  }
};

//Create a task, run with gulp watch
export const watch = gulp.parallel(browserSyncStart, watcher);
```